# Avoid HTML encoding in JMS\Serializer - Laravel

Tags: php, xml, symfony, laravel-5, jms-serializer

I am new to handle XML. I have created an XML using JMS\Serializer.

```
$serializer = \JMS\Serializer\SerializerBuilder::create()->build();

$payload = $serializer->serialize($data, 'xml');
```

I try to serialize the $data array in to XML and pass it as a payload to a  service/API. I am doing this in laravel 5.x.

The only problem I am unable to solve is that I need to avoid html encoding of special characters in the *$payload* XML as I need to pass the string '*a&b*' as '`<Name>a&b</Name>`' instead of the default '`<Name>a&amp;b</Name>`'.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `&` is an invalid character in an XML text sequence and is escaped using html entities (the fact that escaping needs to be done is the reason why `&` on its own is not legal)

Comment: @apokryfos, thank you, I will try some other means instead of sending invalid form of XML.